# Polynomial with x and y in MIPS

Tags: mips

I just have a question on MIPS, I looked everywhere but I could not find examples of MIPS code with an x and y variable.. this is what I have so far, but I am unsure of how the .word 4 works as x = 4. Would I need another lw and sw for the y variable? Also, am I on the right track to solving 32xy + 15x−9y + 48? Thanks a lot!

```
#32xy + 15x−9y + 48 
    .text
    .globl main
main:
    lui $10, 0x1000 #load base register
    lw $2, 0($10)   #Store x in $2
    ori $1, $0, 32  #store 32 in $1
    ori $3, $0, 5   #store y(5) in $3    ### this is just temporary
    ori $4, $0, 15  #store 15 in $4
    ori $5, $0, -9  #store -9 in $5
    ori $6, $0, 48  #store 48 in $6
    multu $1, $2    #32 * x
    mflo $7         #store 32*x in $7
    mult $7, $3     #32x * y
    mflo $7         #32xy = $7
    multu $4, $2    #15 * x
    mflo $8         #15x = $8
    multu $5, $3    #-9 * y
    mflo $9         #-9y = $9 
    addu $8, $8, $9 #15x - 9y = $8
    addu $7, $8, $7 #32xy + 15x-9y = $7
    addu $7, $7, $6 #32xy + 15x-9y + 48 = $7
    sw $7, 4($10)   #store result in poly

    .data
x:      .word   4
poly:   .word   0
```

Comment: I'm confused. You want to know how to add a `y` variable? Use the same pattern as the `x` variable. Reserve space with `.word` and load it into a register using `lw`.

Comment: Thanks, I was just a little confused how it knows which one it is accessing, I'm assuming it goes from n++ every time it creates a new variable(in order)